# How to return average score for precision, recall and F1-score from Sklearn Classification report?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I computed precision, recall and F1-score with Sklearn and get result as below:

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.82      0.87      0.84      2517
          1       0.86      0.81      0.83      2483

avg / total       0.84      0.84      0.84      5000
```

I tried this code:

```
 print("precision_score: ",precision_score(test_y, predicted))
 print("recall_score: ",recall_score(test_y, predicted))
 print("f1_score: ",f1_score(test_y, predicted))
```

It shows p, r and f1 for label 1.

```
 precision_score:  0.857692307692
 recall_score:  0.808296415626
 f1_score:  0.832262077545
```

But how can I return the value for avg/total only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its documented [here in the classification_report page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html):

> The reported averages are a prevalence-weighted macro-average across
>   classes (equivalent to [precision_recall_fscore_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support) with
>   average='weighted').

So to get the avg score you can do:

```
precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(test_y, predicted, 
                                                          average='weighted')
```